# Difference between `&self.stringVal` and `self.stringVal.as_str()`

Tags: rust

Could anyone tell me what's the difference between the 2 ways for returning the `&str` value for `name` of `User`? Both compile but I'm not sure if there's a preferred one.

```rust
pub struct User {
    name: String,
}

impl User {

    pub fn name(&self) -> &str {
        // way1
        &self.name

        // way2
        // self.name.as_str()
    }

}
```

Comment: Rust is "compile ? => yes/no. Yes, you have no problem. No, you need to find a way to compile it."

Comment: both of them work as I tested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `&` on a `String` gives a `&String` and relies on deref coercion to arrive at the desired `&str` type, but `as_str` unambiguously gives a `&str` (while using deref coercion internally). Without deref coercion one would have to write `&s[..]` to turn a `String s` into a `&str`.

> *Deref coercion* converts a reference to a type that implements the `Deref` trait into a reference to another type. For example, deref
> coercion can convert `&String` to `&str` because `String` implements
> the `Deref` trait such that it returns `&str`. Deref coercion is a
> convenience Rust performs on arguments to functions and methods, and
> works only on types that implement the `Deref` trait. It happens
> automatically when we pass a reference to a particular type’s value as
> an argument to a function or method that doesn’t match the parameter
> type in the function or method definition. A sequence of calls to the
> `deref` method converts the type we provided into the type the
> parameter needs. -- [The Rust Programming Language (Chapter 15)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods)

Some programmers may prefer one for its brevity, while others may prefer the other one for its clarity.

Comment: does that mean the 2nd way will be better performance-wise?

Comment: @wayne No, in performance terms they are equivalent.

Comment: @wayne In fact, in pretty much in all other terms as well: <https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#808>

Comment: @wayne [`as_str()` uses deref coercion itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.59.0/src/alloc/string.rs.html#809), so unoptimized it will be slower (one more call). But optimized builds [are the same, even on `-Copt-level=1` only](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/466YrGj6v).